# Predicting trend data for the future using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of data that is Name -> Timestamp -> Count.

For instance:

```
Name    | Timestamp  | Count
=============================
Quant 1 | 12:00      | 5
Quant 1 | 13:00      | 7
Quant 1 | 14:00      | 4
Quant 1 | 15:00      | 2
Quant 1 | 16:00      | 7
Quant 1 | 17:00      | 6
```

I'm creating a graph from this using `AMCharts`. Now I need to do some kind of forecasting. The question is: If the data flows like this, how would this trend looks like within 2 days. Is there a Javascript Lib that's doing that? Couldn't find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm for something like this is called triple exponential smoothing or holt-winters. An example could be: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nostradamus